# What are precision and scale for numeric data types in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

The documentation doesn't have examples.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE

NUMERIC(precision, scale)

I want to use the smallest amount of space to save a positive number that will be at most 100 and I need to accept decimal increments of 0.5

What precision and scale should I use in this case?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `numeric(4, 1)`.

This gives you a total of 4 digits maximum (including the decimal part), with 1 digit reserved for the decimals, so this would store numbers up until `999.9`.

If you can live with numbers that are not greater than `99.9`, then `numeric(3, 1)` is fine.

Comment: Thanks! so precision is # of digits, scale is # of decimal digits.

Comment: @ZachG: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

`NUMERIC(4,1)` will do, but this will also accept decimals such as:

```
55.0
26.3
978.1
```

This is because precision declares maximum of digits a number can hold and scale relates to decimal part. You would also need to validate your input.

If you wish to do this at database level, you could use `CHECK column_name <= 100.0`. Such check could also be extended to accept only numbers with `.0` and `.5` decimal part (see modulo operator).